# Style the progress element in firefox. CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to style the progress bar in firefox using WebKit and following code it works on chrome but not on firefox

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: var(--orange);
  border-radius: 8px;
}


progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

How can I style the progress bar value and bar.

Comment: Try using `::-moz-progress-bar` to style it on Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<progress>` element by changing the background of a few browser-property selectors.

In Firefox, you can use the following:

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: blue; }
```

```css
progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: blue; }/* for Firefox */
progress::-webkit-progress-value { background: blue; }/* for Chrome/safari*/
progress { color: blue; }/* for IE10  */
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="25" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="50" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="75" max="100"></progress><br>
<progress value="100" max="100"></progress><br>
```